# Can we use PK of M2M relation for another M2M table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relational-database

I have some tables like this :

1. batches(id, name)
2. terms(id, name)
3. subjects(id, name)

Batches is having many-to-many relation with Terms in a table called batches_x_terms.

I wanted to create a table to assign Subjects to many terms and those subjects be traceable from Batches too, so I thought of creating a table like this :

batches_x_terms_x_subjects(id, batch_id, term_id, subject_id)

But upon further thinking I concluded that I will have lots of rows in this table for less data and data redundancy will be there too.

So I want to know if I can use M2M table's PK as a FK in M2M relation between :

'batches_x_terms' and 'subjects'

Update 1:
Batches table is having another column  'year'
Batches will have same batches from different years, ex

1. 'Science', 2010
2. 'Science', 2011

Now, suppose every Batch is having 4 terms(semesters) and in each term they have different subjects but some subjects are common between these 2 batches, right?

If I follow 'batches_x_terms' and 'batches_x_subjects' then I won't be able to figure out which subject is taught to which batch in a specific term. I need to classify my data like this :

1. Batches have how many terms?
2. Which subjects are assigned to which Batch in a specific term.
3. Same subjects can be assigned to another Batch in some other term.

Moreover, I have a constraint that I can't assign a different Term ID to every Batch, for a single semester every Batch will have a common Term ID.

I hope this much detail is useful.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  The best approach depends on the data that you need to model, and your question doesn't have enough information to make specific suggestions.

Comment: What additional data can I provide to get a best solution? @GordonLinoff

Comment: Do you maybe mean 'batches_x_terms' and 'terms_x_subjects'? Where terms_x_subjects is "to assign Subjects to many terms" but hopefully "traceable from Batches" via batches_x_terms without batches_x_terms_x_subjects?

Comment: You need to tell us what the database is allowed to look like, or equivalently, what the database is not allowed to look like, if you had all those tables: batches, terms, subjects, batches_x_terms and batches_x_terms_x_subjects (and maybe terms_x_subjects?). In other words, all constraints. In particular, besides PK, UNIQUE and FK constraints, are some values always a function of other values in a row (FDs) and are any base table values always the join of values got by dropping zero or more columns from their own or other base tables' values (JDs)?

Comment: @philipxy The problem is many Batches will have the same term. So I can't assign unique subjects based on Term number.

I have devised a solution that I will need to drop the table 'batches_x_terms' and carry on with 'batches_x_terms_x_subjects' because Batches will be linked to Terms and to Subjects in the same table. I won't need 'batches_x_terms' anymore.

Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: Read the preceding comment. You asked what additional info was needed for best solution & I told you. If you do not collect & use that info then you are just guessing. Eg batches_x_terms_x_subjects (ignoring id) is unnecessary if and only if it equals certain JOINs. This can happen even if "many Batches will have the same term"! Eg maybe best is batch_x_term and batch_x_subject.

Comment: @philipxy Okay. I will provide you with additional info in the question wait.

Comment: 1. You first asked about a best approach in a comment. Now you have added to your post. But what is the (added?) question? 2. You still haven't followed my comments re best approach and given PKs, UNIQUEs, FKs, FDs and JDs of some design. (Which I haven't said how to use yet; but I will.) Now I have asked you three times. 3. I mentioned batch_x_term + batch_x_subject to show that you must check *all possible* joins to see if batch_x_term_x_subject equals one. Your looking has been in fragments so your justifications have been unsound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a column set whose subrow value is unique but doesn't contain any smaller column set whose subrow value is unique as UNIQUE NOT NULL. (I'll limit myself to when NOT NULL is appropriate.) You can define one such set per table as PRIMARY KEY instead. (That's equivalent as a constraint to UNIQUE NOT NULL.)

When a column set subrow value must appear in another table as a subrow value for a unique column set declare a FOREIGN KEY. If the unique column set isn't already declared UNIQUE or PK, do so.

Not only "can" you declare a PK, UNIQUE and/or FK per above, you *should* declare every one that could be. (Some DBMSs will prevent you from declaring FK cycles though.)